# Superclass constructor invocation should be in constructor body

Tags: error-handling, reactjs, webstorm, ecmascript-6, superclass

I write React class constructor use es6, but there is a red highlight error in webstorm9 editor
here is the part of code:

```
class AssetSelectDialog extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.any,
    pageState: React.PropTypes.string,
    pageStatus: React.PropTypes.string,
    handleCancel: React.PropTypes.func,
    handleSave: React.PropTypes.func
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.PAGE_STATUS = {
        SHOW: 'SHOW',
        SELECT: 'SELECT'
    };
    this.state = {
        data: this.props.data || {},
        pageState: this.props.pageState || CONST.STATUS.EDIT,
        pageStatus: this.props.pageStatus || this.PAGE_STATUS.SHOW 
    };
}
```

there error was found in `super(props);` and the message is `Superclass constructor invocation should be in constructor body`.
the code is run ok in babel., how can I fixed it?

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://twitter.com/webstormide/status/565439940755218432

Comment: your code is not terminated correctly in several places. **DON'T** use semicolons inside class declaration, and use proper indentation to see what you've missed

Comment: @Amit What's wrong with semi-colons in class definitions?

Comment: thanks very much. the code is just a part of that class.the problem was that the webstorm bug.It has fixed in version 10.4 .

Comment: @RGraham: class definitions don't consist of statements. It's similarly wrong as using semicolons in object literals, or omitting the commata

Comment: @Bergi I haven't checked the proposal for property assignment, but in Babel at least it doesn't throw an error. So it's maybe redundant, but certainly not the same as putting one inside an object literal as that would throw a syntax error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug in WebStorm, [WEB-14601](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14601) is fixed in WebStorm 10.0.4